# Which is faster?: add view dynamically VS add view in .xml

Tags: android

I have a lot of views(TextView, View etc...) in my android app and I have two choices.(as you can see in title)

My question is -

Which one takes few resources and time when executed: add view programmatically or add view in a layout xml file manually?

Comment: Adding views dynamically will reduce code readability as a lot of lines are required, eg: to add  an EditText for password, you'll have to set it's inputType, its minimum length, check it's strength, it's position etc. So code becomes heavy and line of code also increases.

Answer (score 1):

Adding views programatically is faster. When adding views from layout XML, it adds them in the same way but in addition, it needs to walk through that XML and use a lot of reflexion.